# Defining custom option keys for tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I want to implement a option key for a custom `tcolorbox` environment, where when I include it in the optional arguments it expands to something like `underlay = {<tikz code>}` .

In the following code, I want to substitute the `underlay = {...}` with a simple key like `quotation`. My goal is to reproduce the second box like this: `\begin{sigbox}[quotation]`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
%
%
\newtcolorbox{sigbox}[1][]{%
    enhanced, remember, colback=yellow!25!white, arc=0pt, boxrule=0pt, leftrule=3 ex %
, colframe=yellow!85!red!33!white %
, underlay = {%
    \path[fill=yellow!25!white] (frame.south west) -- ([yshift=3 ex]frame.south west) -- 
    ([xshift = 1.5 ex ,yshift=1.5 ex]frame.south west) -- ([xshift = 3 ex , % 
    yshift = 3 ex]frame.south west) -- ([xshift = 3 ex]frame.south west) -- cycle;
    }%
, overlay = {%
    \path ([xshift=1.5 ex, yshift = -2.25 ex]frame.north west) node %
    {\textcolor{tcbcolback!33!white}{\LARGE\textbf{!}}};%
    }%
     ,#1 %
     }%
     %
\begin{document}
%
\begin{sigbox}
\lipsum[7]
\end{sigbox}
%
\begin{sigbox}[%
underlay = {%
    \path ([xshift=1.5 ex, yshift = -5.5 ex]frame.north west) node %
    {\textcolor{tcbcolback!33!white}{\LARGE\textbf{"}}};%
    }%
]%
\lipsum[8]
\end{sigbox}
%
\end{document}
```

Should I just create a macro ala `\newcommand{\quotation}{underlay =  {<tikz code>}}`; can I implement this with some conditional expression from e.g. `xstring`; or do I have to learn how `pgfkeys` works?

Comment: Which approach is best depends a lot on what you want to do exactly, which, however, it is very unclear to me. It would be of much help, if you could provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) in addition to something that shows what you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is `\tcbset` which can help you to create custom styles (I simplified the code a bit):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
    quotation/.style={
        overlay = {
            \node[text=tcbcolback!33!white, font=\LARGE\bfseries] at 
                ([xshift=1.5ex, yshift=-2.25ex]frame.north west) {"};
        }
    }
}

\newtcolorbox{sigbox}[1][]{
    enhanced, remember, colback=yellow!25!white, arc=0pt, boxrule=0pt, leftrule=3ex, colframe=yellow!85!red!33!white,
    underlay = {
        \path[fill=yellow!25!white] (frame.south west) -- 
            ([yshift=3ex]frame.south west) -- 
            ([xshift=1.5ex, yshift=1.5ex]frame.south west) -- 
            ([xshift=3ex, yshift=3ex]frame.south west) -- 
            ([xshift=3ex]frame.south west) -- cycle;
        },
    overlay = {
        \node[text=tcbcolback!33!white, font=\LARGE\bfseries] at 
            ([xshift=1.5ex, yshift=-2.25ex]frame.north west) {!};
    },
    #1 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{sigbox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{sigbox}

\begin{sigbox}[quotation]
\lipsum[2]
\end{sigbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You should always be careful not to overwrite existing styles, of course.